# can add subfolder to github repo

Tags: git, github

[image]

i have tried to add the Website folder to my github repo but when i click on it it wont open you can see here that its got a different icon than usually i have tried to use `git add Website` but that didn't work i also tried `git add -i`  to add untracked files and it seemed to work when i went inside the Website folder itself but it wouldn't push to the origin unless i was in the original folder outside the Website subfolder and when i completed the push as you can see the commit says added untracked files but i still can look in the files. The folder has files in it

Comment: Is there anything in the Website folder?  Or is it empty?

Comment: The `Website` directory seems to be a symlink.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Not a symlink — a nested repository.

Comment: @phd Symlinks and submodules seem to have the same visual representation on GitHub, but my submodules indicate the commit hash they point to (see [here](https://github.com/bewuethr/dotfiles/tree/master/.vim/bundle)), so it still looks more like a symlink to me?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Seems you're right. My test is at https://github.com/phdru/test-submodules-symlinks

Comment: so what do i do to make the subfolder not a symlink

Answer (score 2):

Try `git add .` , `git commit -m 'message'`, and then `git push`?